# How to prevent this select forms from taking new lines when narrower than 769px on bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm on bootstrap 3.3.7

**CODE:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="select_year">Year</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="select_year" style="width: 96px"></select>

                <label for="select_month">Month</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="select_month" style="width: 96px"></select>

                <label for="select_day">Day</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="select_day" style="width: 96px"></select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Those code is for date select form.

But the select forms takes new lines when browser is narrower than 769px.

How to remove these taking new lines?

How to make these forms be inline when browser is narrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/bkzaksve/10/

Create form groups for every select and label pair. In the form tag add the class

```
col-xs-12
```

like:

```
<form class="form-inline col-xs-12">
```

Do check the above link for more clarity